# Is "maiden speech" regarded as politically incorrect?

Tags: british-english, political-correctness, politics

Some people use "inaugural speech" instead of [maiden speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maiden_speech). For example, from the [Twitter account of the Australian Sex Party](https://twitter.com/aussexparty/status/697747255865053184):

> From one year ago, the Inaugural Speech of @FionaPattenMLC
>   http://fionapatten.com/parliament-item/fiona-patten-inaugural-speech/ … #SpringSt

Looking at Google NGrams for British English (presumably more relevant than US English for Westminster Parliamentary systems), I can [see](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inaugural%20speech%2Cmaiden%20speech&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinaugural%20speech%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaiden%20speech%3B%2Cc0) that "maiden speech" is on the decline, and "inaugural speech" is on the rise.

Some conservatives suspect it's because "maiden speech" is regarded as politically incorrect. [How political correctness threatens Australian culture](http://newsweekly.com.au/article.php?id=3462) claims as an example of political correctness "A member of parliament's maiden speech is now called their "first speech"" and Paul Fletcher's [blog post on his maiden speech](http://paulfletcher.com.au/paul-s-blog/item/110-pauls-blog-maiden-speech.html) says "Being something of a traditionalist, I referred to it as my “Maiden Speech” even though this is now thought to be somewhat politically incorrect.  Apparently the preferred term is the rather more prosaic “First Speech”."

Is this suspicion true? Is "maiden speech" regarded as politically incorrect?

Comment: Searching [parliament.uk](http://www.parliament.uk/search/results/?q=%22inaugural+speech%22) I find 4437 hits for "maiden speech", against only 98 for "inaugural speech". It seems to be a fairly smart search, in that the latter automatically included hits for "inauguration speech". But more tellingly, apart from a reference to *Churchill's* inaugural speech, all the others seem to be references to various foreign presidents, not British MPs. Which doesn't surprise me, since I don't think they mean the same thing anyway (a maiden speech could be given months or *years* after "taking office").

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "maiden speech". **Maiden voyage** OTOH... This American finds it easier to imagine a ship as a maiden than Churchill as a maiden. :)

Comment: An "inaugural" speech is **not** a maiden speech. That said, there's no politically correct substitute for *maiden speech* that I know of yet. One could do with *debut* speech, perhaps, which again suffers from the same problem as *inaugural speech*.

Comment: @TimRomano Google it :)

Comment: @Kris: I know it exists. I said I've never *heard* it.

Comment: In the US I suspect it's more likely to be regarded as "quaint".

Comment: The Leftist political orientation of this question is objectionable. This site is about English, not about Marxist theories of deconstructing English. (I only wish that I could boast that this were my *maiden comment.*)

Comment: @thb what does my question have to do with Marxism?

Comment: Still in common use in the Federal and Provincial Houses of Parliament in Canada.  We have had a new national as well as a new provincial government installed here recently.  Federally, a great deal of hay has been made over the equal number of male and female cabinet members.  Provincially the house was taken by social democrats, led by a woman, with a very high proportion of women elected.  Members of both houses have been busy giving their maiden speeches.  If the tradition is thought to be sexist, it does not seem to have gained much traction here.

Answer (score 1):

An "inaugural" speech is not a maiden speech. That said, there's no politically correct substitute for "maiden speech" that I know of yet. One could do with "debut speech," perhaps, which again suffers from the same problem as *inaugural speech*.

([c-span](http://www.c-span.org/video/?c4548130/bernie-sanders-debut-speech-congress) August 13, 2015)

> Bernie Sanders' **debut speech** to congress: Topics covered in his **first speech as a house representative** include: single-payer healthcare, income inequality, and infrastructure jobs

[emphasis mine]

But then,
([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/41y6p4/eli5_how_is_sarah_palin_such_a_high_profile/) Jan 21, 2016)

> She gained national visibility as John McCain's running mate in the 2008 presidential election. Her debut came during a speech in which she effectively shredded Obama and seemed to really throw him off his game for a week or two.
>   
>   Following the debut speech, the Democrats and their allies in the media seemed to make it their top priority to personally destroy her.

and
([Intellectual Conservative](http://intellectualconservative.com/jeb-bush-makes-a-grand-supply-side-entrance/) Feb 22, 2015)

> The Republican Party has an embarrassment of riches in good prospective presidential contenders for next year’s race. Thus Gov. Jeb Bush’s debut speech — on February 4th, in Detroit, the start of of his “Right To Rise” tour — took on heightened importance.